# How to remove strings(made of special characters) with spaces using regex?

Tags: python, regex

Programming in Python.

I have two lists made of strings:

1. List1: Strings are made of alphabets such as a, b, c, d, ' ' (single space),
2. List2: Strings are made of special characters $, €, &, %, ' '(single space).

Example:

```
list1 = ['a    ', 
         'ab   ', 
         'ba  c', 
         ' a b ',
         'abd  ']

list2 = ['$    ', 
         '€&   ', 
         '€%  &', 
         ' $ € ',
         '€&$  ']
```

The actual problem has more than 5 elements in both the lists.
The goal is:

```
1. to remove elements like: 'ba  c', ' a b ' from list1
2. to remove elements like: '€%  &', ' $ € ' from list2
```

I was able to achieve goal 1 in two steps:

Step 1:

```
list1[:] = [word for word in list1 if not (word[0] == ' ')]
```

Step 2:

```
import re
regex1 = r"\s[\w]\s*" 
list1[:] = [word for word in list1 if not (re.search(regex1, word))]
```

For list2, I was able to:

```
list2[:] = [word for word in list2 if not (word[0] == ' ')]
```

which removes elements such as

```
' $ € '
```

but

```
regex2 = r"\s[\W]\s*" # on list 2
```

does not remove elements such as

```
'€%  &'
```

Questions:

1. What will be a regex to combine step1 and step2 applied on list1?
2. What is the correct regex instead of regex2?
3. If list1 and list2 are concatenated

   ```
   list12 =['a    ', 
            'ab   ', 
            'ba  c', 
            ' a b ',
            'abd  ',
            '$    ', 
            '€&   ', 
            '€%  &', 
            ' $ € ',
            '€&$  ']
   ```

what would be the regex to remove elements such as:

```
'ba  c', ' a b ', '€%  &', ' $ € '
```

Remove the element from the list if the following pattern is present:

1. If the first letter of the string is ' ' (single space), e.g., ' abcd', ' €€$%'
2. If there is ' ' (single space) between characters of the string e.g., '€%  &', 'a b c', '% &€€'

Any help is appreciated. Thanks. :)

Comment: when you say "remove elements such as" I sense you want to say there's a pattern there. I cannot see it though. Could you clarify what pattern exactly do you have in mind ?

Comment: What criteria makes them something to remove?

Comment: Can you give a clear definition on what to remove and what not?

Comment: Criteria: A string (made of alphabets or special characters) is considered as a word. If a string has space in between the characters or if it starts with a space then it is not considered as a word. Therefore such strings should be detected and removed from the list. By remove, I mean such strings should not be an element of the list. I have edited the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the pattern is to match left-aligned words, the code may be like this:

```
list12[:] = [word for word in list12 if re.match(r'^\S+\s*$', word)]
```

This code will match only the strings that contain spaces in the end.
The result is:

```
a    
ab   
abd  
$    
€&   
€&$
```

Comment: 10 seconds late for the same answer haha

Comment: The ^ at the beginning is implied in `re.match()`.  And both, the leading ^ and the trailing $, are implied in `re.fullmatch()`.